# Microsoft Edge не сбрасывает значение input range после обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, html, браузер, microsoft-edge

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0">
```

Как видите `autocomplete="off"` присутствует, но эффекта не даёт.

Понимаю что значение можно и через JS сбрасывать, но в других браузерах нормально же...

Или это <s>баг</s> фича, Edge?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить еще 1 инпут рядом с `display: none`

Comment: @Дмытрык, К сожалению не помогло...

Comment: В Хроме, такую проблему, я еще решал обернув инпут в форму. Тогда начал работать `autocomplete=off`

Comment: @Дмытрык, Пробовал не работает, ни в одном браузере кроме Edge, таких проблем нет.

Comment: А у меня в Edge не воспроизводится. А вы как страницу обновляете?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, По разному))) Ctrl + F5, F5, кнопочкой..

Comment: Видать еще от версии Edge зависит)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, Наверное, у меня: 42.17134.1.0